# Should I capitalize in this case?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I presented two solutions to a problem in an article. I called them solution 1 and solution 2.

> Solution 1 is better than solution 2 in terms of the efficiency.

When I refer to either one of them, which one is correct?

1. solution 1 (or 2)
2. **S**olution 1 (or 2)
3. **the** solution 1 (or 2)

Comment: In what context?  In a title you'd use title case.  In a paragraph you'd probably not use title case, unless you were referring to a title in your write up.

Comment: @JamesK I added it in the question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: If you are using Solution 1 and Solution 2 as proper nouns, then you must capitalise them each time they are used as you would with any other proper noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No capitals and no articles. "Solution 1 is better than solution 2."

But if you use ordinal numbers, then do use "the":  "The first solution is better than the second."

Comment: ... no capitals except the usual one at the start of the sentence :-)